# Create checkboxes columns dynamically angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to dynamically create columns of checkboxes in a dropdown using angular . I use bootstrapping . Each checkbox item may or may not have children related.

The solution I found was to put everything inside a div ( .col -sm -4 , the grid system bootstrap , but the items were not aligned properly.

Follow the code and the result of this action: (put the line in red for easy orientation)

```
 <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="font-size:14px; padding: 16px 15px">Tipo peca <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="border:1px solid #dcdcdc;border-radius: 3px; width:1000px;">
                <li ng-repeat="result in vm.listAnuncios.anunciosAgrupadosPorTipoPeca">
                    <div class="col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid red;">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.selectAll($event)" />
                        <span class="lbl padding-8" style="color:#8b8b8b; font-size:12px !important">
                            {{result.nome}}
                            <span style="color:#b0b0b0;">{{result.total}}</span>
                        </span>

                        <ul id="tp_{{result.subTipoPecaId}}">
                            <li ng-repeat="peca in result.pecasAgrupadas" style="margin-left:25px;">

                                <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.selectAll($event)" />
                                <span class="lbl padding-8" style="color:rgba(139, 139, 139, 0.88); font-size:12px !important">
                                    {{peca.nome}}
                                    <span style="color:#b0b0b0;">{{peca.total}}</span>
                                </span>

                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
```

(Please disregard the Portuguese in the code.)

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m7PT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code example.
If you need any change in requirement give me full code including data.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7843b/11/)

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TeamListCtrl" class="checkboxList">
    <div id="teamCheckboxList">
      <li ng-repeat="result in results">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="border:1px solid red;">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.selectAll($event)" />
          <span class="lbl padding-8" style="color:#8b8b8b; font-size:12px !important">
                            {{result.name}}
                            <span style="color:#b0b0b0;">{{result.total}}</span>
          </span>

          <ul id="tp_{{result.subTipoPecaId}}">
            <li ng-repeat="peca in pecas" style="margin-left:25px;">

              <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.selectAll($event)" />
              <span class="lbl padding-8" style="color:rgba(139, 139, 139, 0.88); font-size:12px !important">
                                    {{peca.name}}
                                    <span style="color:#b0b0b0;">{{peca.total}}</span>
              </span>

            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>

      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Dipali Vasani,
But I am building the checks dynamically. Some may have one or more children and this is causing some error in rendering. The image you can see that the groups are not nested correctly. Even so , thank you for your reply.

Comment: If you have not got solution ye, share the json, if I can help.